# Facing java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/client/MongoClients error while running the java app

Tags: java, mongodb, docker, maven, runtime-error

I am trying to deploy one sample java mongo dockerized application for testing purpose. However even after successful build, I am unable to run it. I have gone through official mongodb documentation and a lot of examples online but nothing seems to be working. Currentl, I am stuck and need someone's help.

Here is my sample pom.xml:

```
    <project  xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.mongoapp</groupId>
<artifactId>mongodb</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>mongodb</name>
<description>Sample App for java</description>

<properties>
    <!-- <java.version>11</java.version>   -->
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>  
    <!-- <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>  
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>   -->
    <maven-compiler-plugin.source>8</maven-compiler-plugin.source>
    <maven-compiler-plugin.target>8</maven-compiler-plugin.target>
    <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.10.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
    <mongodb-driver-sync.version>4.4.1</mongodb-driver-sync.version>
</properties>   
    
<dependencies> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
        <version>${mongodb-driver-sync.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>  



<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
            <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin> -->
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>${maven-compiler-plugin.source}</source>
            <target>${maven-compiler-plugin.target}</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
            <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
        <plugin> 

        <!-- Building an executable jar -->

        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>

            <!-- give full qualified name of your main class-->
              <mainClass>com.mongoapp.mongodb.connection.JavaMongoDemo</mainClass>

            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
        </plugin>

</plugins>
```

My main.java file is as below:

```
package com.mongoapp.mongodb.connection;

import com.mongodb.*;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection; 
import org.bson.Document;  
public class JavaMongoDemo {  
public static void main(String[] args){  
try{  
MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create( "mongodb://localhost:27017" );
//---------- Creating DataBase ---------------------------//  
MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("sampledb");  
}catch(Exception e){  
System.out.println(e);  
}  
}  
}
```

Below is the error I am getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/client/MongoClients
        at com.mongoapp.mongodb.connection.JavaMongoDemo.main(JavaMongoDemo.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.client.MongoClients
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        ... 1 more
```

What can i do to resolve the issue??

Comment: Maven jar plugin produces an executable jar that is not self contained: it lists its dependencies in the manifest but it does not copy them. You have 2 options: 1. copy dependencies with maven dependency plugin 2. Build an uber-jar with maven assembly plugin